# Multisite .htaccess simple redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 domain names pointing to same Web root host folder, so sharing the same .htaccess file, too.

I'm trying that `www.domain1.com/blog` redirects to `www.domain2.com/blog`. All without afecting `www.domain2.com/blog` requests, ponting to same .htaccess file, because on that case we enter in a infinite loop  :-)

Just to understand me, in programming it would be something like:

```
    if ( (domain=='www.domain1.com') && (folder='/blog/') ) {
    redirect to 'http://www.domain2.com/blog/'
    }
```

I'm sure it simple, but I don't get it...
Thank you so much to all of you!

UPDATE:

finally I did it with that code:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
    RewriteRule .* http://www.domain2.com/blog [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^blog$ www.domain2.com/blog [NC,L,QSA,NS]
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks Elfocrash, but it doesn't: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^blog\.xml$ www.domain2.com/blog [NC,L,QSA,NS]
</IfModule>` When I'm at `http://www.domain1.com/blog/` doesn't redirect to `http://www.domain2.com/blog/`

Comment: Remove the "\.xml" on the RewriteRule. I used one of my rewrites and i forgot to remove it.

Comment: I already changed it: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xplora\.cat$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^blog$ www.xplora.eu/blog [NC,L,QSA,NS]
</IfModule>`but it doesn't work anyway. You can see that opening http://www.xplora.cat/blog/

Comment: Hi Elfocrash! Finally I solved it. Thank anyway! :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that mate. Would you share what it was? Thanks

Comment: Hi again, sure, I have updated my question sharing the solution   ;-)